# Get JIRA issue properties using JRJC search

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

To search for JIRA issues in Java we can use this REST

```
/api/2.0.alpha1/search?jql&startAt&maxResults
```

for example:

```
/api/2.0.alpha1/search?assignee=mehran
```

but unfrotunately, according to the [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/4.3/), the result is in this format:

```
{
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 1,
    "issues": [
        {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2.0/jira/rest/api/2.0/issue/HSP-1",
            "key": "HSP-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access the other properties of issues, like: title, description, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, why are you looking at an ancient version (**4.3**) of the API documentation? The latest is [7.2.4](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/), for example.

If you're also running JIRA 4.3 then you're S-O-L as at that point their REST API was in a very early state.

However if your JIRA instance is newer (if it isn't, **UPGRADE**) then open up the proper documentation @ `https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/{yourVersion}/`. At one point the `search` endpoint was improved so you could expand issues and specify exactly which custom field values you want to retrieve.